# in app product list is not appearing under apk of developer console

Tags: android

Hiii, to everyone... I am trapped while testing in app purchase, when i upload my .apk to Google play developer console. I am not getting "In app product" link under my unpublished .apk. I have read many docs, but I am getting confused. Any suggestion will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.